# MongoDB, Mongoose with NULL argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is an extract from Practicle Node.js. I have come across a find query, which I could not understand. The following is the find query with it’s parameters. Could not find any explanation.

```
db.article.find({published: true}, null, {sort: {_id:-1}})
```

Could someone, please explain, what does the NULL indicate here?

Comment: Isn't that a shell command, not Mongoose?

Answer (score 3):

`.find()` function takes maximum of 4 arguments.

```
Model.find(query, fields, options, callback)
// fields and options can be omitted
```

Means that second argument `fields` is compulsory. In order to pass third argument option (in your case `sort`), you have to pass `null` as second argument.
Second argument is projection argument, with that you can show or hide fields from output/result.

As of the 4.1.x release of Mongoose, You can alternatively use following method to achieve same,

```
db.article.find({published: true}).sort({_id: -1})
```

Comment: I'm very new to mongoose and this is the second time I've had to look something up which should be documented in their api.  Thanks for filling in their unfortunate gaps

Answer (score 0):

The [**`.find`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) method takes four arguments. The `null` here means that there is no optional field to return and is needed here because so that options `{sort: {_id:-1}}` can be pass to the `.find` method and not considered as projection.

Comment: I think the .find() takes two parameters as described here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/ Moreover, the query does return results.

Comment: Yes but I think here the mongoose driver is been used